# Jquery DIY slider multiple usage issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I'm using DIY Slider but there's a problem that I couldn't handle. When I try to use this slider more than one times in one page, the second one will not run.

I tried every possible things that my mind finds.

```
$(".slider").diyslider({
    width: "400px", // width of the slider
    height: "200px", // height of the slider
    display: 1, // number of slides you want it to display at once
    loop: false // disable looping on slides
}); // this is all you need!

// use buttons to change slide
$("#go-left").bind("click", function(){
    // Go to the previous slide
    $(".slider").diyslider("move", "back");
});
$("#go-right").bind("click", function(){
    // Go to the previous slide
    $(".slider").diyslider("move", "forth");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bj4yZ/155/ - This is the working "not working" demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is change the id's of every element. If you don't do that, and just copy&paste the html and js, all events will be attached to the first slider.

http://jsfiddle.net/bj4yZ/788/

```
<button id="go-left">&laquo;</button> <button id="go-right">&raquo;</button>

<div class="slider"><!-- The slider -->
    <div><!-- A mandatory div used by the slider -->
        <!-- Each div below is considered a slide -->
        <div class="a">Div #1</div>
        <div class="b">Div #2</div>
        <div class="c">Div #3</div>
        <div class="d">Div #4</div>
        <div class="e">Div #5</div>
    </div>
</div>

<button id="go-left2">&laquo;</button> <button id="go-right2">&raquo;</button>

<div class="slider2"><!-- The slider -->
    <div><!-- A mandatory div used by the slider -->
        <!-- Each div below is considered a slide -->
        <div class="a">Div #1</div>
        <div class="b">Div #2</div>
        <div class="c">Div #3</div>
        <div class="d">Div #4</div>
        <div class="e">Div #5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the js

```
$(".slider").diyslider({
    width: "400px", // width of the slider
    height: "200px", // height of the slider
    display: 3, // number of slides you want it to display at once
    loop: false // disable looping on slides
}); // this is all you need!

// use buttons to change slide
$("#go-left").bind("click", function(){
    // Go to the previous slide
    $(".slider").diyslider("move", "back");
});
$("#go-right").bind("click", function(){
    // Go to the previous slide
    $(".slider").diyslider("move", "forth");
});



$(".slider2").diyslider({
    width: "400px", // width of the slider
    height: "200px", // height of the slider
    display: 3, // number of slides you want it to display at once
    loop: false // disable looping on slides
}); // this is all you need!

// use buttons to change slide
$("#go-left2").bind("click", function(){
    // Go to the previous slide
    $(".slider2").diyslider("move", "back");
});
$("#go-right2").bind("click", function(){
    // Go to the previous slide
    $(".slider2").diyslider("move", "forth");
});
```

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! I just didn't try to change button names. Cool!

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty safely separate things with an `each()` on the slider calls.

Here is a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/plastclens/52bck5tq/)

Diyslider is just a bit too stripped down to do this on it's own.